# angular-js Directives invoke sibling Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

what i want is very simple with jquery but in angular i have no idea how i can do that with best approach.

**scenario**

i have list of element (Basically custom directives) in each element when clicked i show simple div inside that element by adding show=true. when user clicks other element from list i want to hide previously showed div then show that specific div on that specific item which is now clicked .

[image: wihtout div]
[image: with div]

```
$scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
    if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
      $scope.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
      $scope.shownGroup = group;
    }
  };
  $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
    return $scope.shownGroup === group;
  };
```

Found some kind of solution but still searching the best approach

[Example](http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/uJkCz?editors=101)

Comment: can you bring your code in fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could write a `$broadcast` in the `$root` scope which would tell all your image widgets to hide their div.

Something like this (just a sketch):

```
angular.module('eventExample', [])
    .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.hideAll = function () {
            $scope.$broadcast('hideAllEvent');
        };
    }])
    .directive('myImageWidget', function ($scope) {
        $scope.$on('hideAllEvent', function () {
            $scope.show = false;
        });

        $scope.clickMe = function () {
            // Trigger a broadcast from the root scope, so that all widgets
            // listening to the 'hideAllEvent' will set show to false,
            $scope.$root.hideAll();
            // Locally (just in the widget that was clicked) set show to true.
            $scope.show = true;
       };
    });
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <div my-image-widget ng-click="clickMe()" ng-show="show"></div>
    <div my-image-widget ng-click="clickMe()" ng-show="show"></div>
    <div my-image-widget ng-click="clickMe()" ng-show="show"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

[This](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation) part of the docs is super instructive.

Comment: Thats Good solution but its similar to solution i found and edit in my question .i wish there is any why in which i didn't have to do any logic in controller just my directive do some magic and hide others .